# Spring Boot 2.1 cache actuator not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have setup a simple spring boot application based on version 2.1 (https://github.com/dkellenb/spring-boot-2.1-cache-actuator-missing). I cannot find the reason why the cache actuator is not available at http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches .

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "helloWorld")
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello world");
    }
}
```

And for the pom.xml i have added cache and actuator:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also i have tested with

```
endpoints.caches.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,cache
```

Note that Cache Actuator is available with JMX, but on on web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason was:

- cache is not exposed by default (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints)
- There was a typo for the exposure, it should be `caches` (plural)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that the actuator must be be in the version spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar.

My previous version was spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar. In this version CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration not exist. This class is responsible for creating the "cachesEndpoint" bean if the "cacheManager" bean is present in the application.

Try the version 2.1.3.

Comment: You are right. CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration was introduced at 2.1.0